# Template specialization enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, enable-if

I am trying to specialize a template this way:

```
class PropertyBase
{
public:
    SfPropertyBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    virtual ~SfPropertyBase() {}

    string Name;

    virtual bool FromString(Object* obj, string str) = 0;

};


template< typename T>
class Property : public SfPropertyBase
{
public:
    Property(string name) : SfPropertyBase(name)
    {
        //specific to Property stuff
    }



    template<typename U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<(std::is_class<U>::value && std::is_pointer<U>::value), bool>::type
    FromString(Object* obj, string str)
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }

    template<typename U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<U>::value || !std::is_pointer<U>::value), bool>::type
    FromString(Object* obj, string str)
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, when I try to initialize an instance of this class:

```
 auto prop = new Property<int>("IntProperty");
```

I get `invalid new-expression of abstract class type Property<int>`. I understand that there is an abstract function in `PropertyBase`, but I also provide both specializations for `Property`, where `T` is a class and where it isn't.

What is going on and how to fix it?

Note: what I want to achieve is to specialize `FromString` if T is a class/pointer and all the other cases.

Comment: `std::is_pointer<U>` does not implies `std::is_class<U>` ?

Comment: Just to be safe, I am trying many things to make it work and this is my current version, might be unnecessary

Comment: Actually it is working as intended only if I specify is_pointer (not both)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the `FromString` in `Property` are function template, they can't *override* the non-template `virtual` function of the base class. (In fact functions templates cannot be [`virtual` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)).

You could add another non-template `FromString` in `Property`; and you can ensure the overriding by using the keyword [`orverride`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). e.g.

```
bool FromString(Object* obj, string str) override {
    return FromString<>(obj, str);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JoAbaq2ZnlDdSd75)

Comment: Note that there will be an ambiguity if all the functions are named the same. This will leak implemenation details, since `FromString(...)` will always be ambiguous on the derived type, and require `<>` to call the implementation unambiguously. Renaming the templates will avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

A function template cannot be used as an overrider for a non-template virtual function. A function template is not a function, it's a recipe  for creating functions *on demand* when a call is made.

Code will have to call `FromString` on your derived class object directly for SFINAE to work. If you want to provide a different overrider based on the template parameter type, one approach is to go via an intermediate base.

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct FromStringProvider;

template<typename T>
struct FromStringProvider<T, typename std::enable_if<(std::is_class<U>::value && std::is_pointer<U>::value)>::type> : SfPropertyBase {
    bool FromString(Object* obj, string str) override
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
};
```

If you need access to the deriving class, then a CRTP based approach can be used. Just pass the deriving class as an extra parameter and rely on its static interface to access the parts you need.

This alternative approach is especially useful if you have sets of virtual functions, all under the same conditions.